# Is there a cleaner way to test functions that use functions that require user input in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I am writing a [CLI question asking library](https://gitlab.com/starshell/question) for my first Rust project since I will probably be using it anyway, and I cannot find a clean way to test the `terminal` method of the builder pattern, which using the configuration gets user input and returns an answer.

```
pub fn confirm(&mut self) -> Answer {
    self.yes_no();
    self.build_prompt();
    let prompt = self.prompt.clone();
    let valid_responses = self.valid_responses.clone().unwrap();
    loop {
        let stdio = io::stdin();
        let input = stdio.lock();
        let output = io::stdout();
        if let Ok(response) = prompt_user(input, output, &prompt) {
            for key in valid_responses.keys() {
                if *response.trim().to_lowercase() == *key {
                    return valid_responses.get(key).unwrap().clone();
                }
            }
            self.build_clarification();
        }
    }
}
```

Looking for a solution I discovered [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370126/how-can-i-test-stdin-and-stdout) which allowed me to write tests for the function that prompts the user for input using [`Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html). It does not let me change the user input to the `confirm()` function for each test of `Question::new("Continue?").confirm()` though so I tried using conditional compilation, and came up with the following.

```
#[cfg(not(test))]
fn prompt_user<R, W>(mut reader: R, mut writer: W, question: &str) -> Result<String, std::io::Error>
where
    R: BufRead,
    W: Write,
{
    write!(&mut writer, "{}", question)?;
    let mut s = String::new();
    reader.read_line(&mut s)?;
    Ok(s)
}

#[cfg(test)]
fn prompt_user<R, W>(mut reader: R, mut writer: W, question: &str) -> Result<String, std::io::Error>
where
    R: BufRead,
    W: Write,
{
    use tests;
    Ok(unsafe { tests::test_response.to_string() })
}
```

And in the `tests` module I use a global variable:

```
pub static mut test_response: &str = "";

#[test]
fn simple_confirm() {
    unsafe { test_response = "y" };
    let answer = Question::new("Continue?").confirm();
    assert_eq!(Answer::YES, answer);
}
```

This works as long as I only run tests with a single thread, but also no longer allows me to test the real user input function. Not really a problem for such a small crate but it is very messy. I did not see any solutions to do this from any available testing libraries.

Comment: *It does not let me change the input to the function for each input* — Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: Because `reader`, `writer`, and `question` are all passed to `prompt_user()` inside of the `confirm()` function I can not manipulate the input like I can when testing the `prompt_user()` function itself. So I am unable to automate tests involving `confirm()`.

Comment: So, are you saying that `confirm`, which doesn't have any arguments, doesn't support dependency injection? If so, I'm not sure what help we can provide. Yes, you have to have some way of injecting the dependencies, arguments are the simplest, but you can also have struct fields. What prevents you from having arguments on `confirm` to inject the dependencies you need?

Comment: I didn't want `confirm` to have any arguments just as a matter of public interface design. I didn't even think about using struct fields for the arguments to `prompt_user` in `confirm` though. I think that could work and let me modify the input source while testing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Stack Overflow question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370126/how-can-i-test-stdin-and-stdout), you should generally avoid hard-wiring external dependencies (a.k.a. I/O) if you want testability:

- disk access,
- terminal access,
- network access,
- database access,
- **time** access.

In all such cases, I recommend using *Dependency Injection*:

- create a clean interface (trait) to describe the allowed actions (don't overdo it, YAGNI!),
- implement the interface for "production" use, with the real external dependency behind it,
- implement a "mock" of the interface for "test" use.

Then, when writing:

- a function which requires access to this resource, pass it as argument,
- a method which requires access to this resource, pass it as either argument or in the constructor of the object.

Finally, instantiate the production dependencies in main, and forward them from there.

---

Tricks, not treats:

- It may be useful to create an `Environment` structure which contains all such interfaces, rather than passing heaps of arguments to each function; however functions which only require one/two resource(s) should take those explicitly to make it clear what they use,
- I have found it useful to pass the *timestamp* rather than the *clock* from which it is obtained in the past... just because multiple calls to `now()` may return different results as the time passes.

Comment: +1. I was given the impression that DI is impossible in Rust previously by comments made on /r/rust, pleased to see it is still possible.

Comment: @user9993: Rust has no *Dependency Injection Framework*, but it is still possible to pass the dependencies manually. The next hurdle is genericity & references, I advise to use either `Rc<RefCell<Trait>>` or its multi-threaded counterpart to hold the traits: external dependencies are slow compared to CPU time anyway, the extra memory allocation and virtual calls will barely be a blip on the radar.

Comment: From my experience you can take this approach without using trait objects. For example when I test an application protocol, I'll have written against Read/BufWrite traits. Rather than pass a trait object however, I just use static dispatch. You get the testability without introducing any runtime penalty.