# Testing a Component with a TcpStream

Tags: testing, rust

I have created a component that creates a `std::net::TcpStream` and over its lifetime of course reads from it and writes to it. Now I would like to write tests for it; does it connect to the right address? Does it send the correct data? Can it handle receiving invalid data? However, as I have only started using Rust, like, three days ago, I am unsure as to how to proceed. In Java (which I have been doing substantially longer than Rust) I would have at least the following possibilities:

1. Create a test TCP server to collect data sent to it and to control what is being sent back.
2. Extract the I/O operations into a trait, implement that trait for `TcpStream` and a `TestTcpStream`, and use the `TestTcpStream` during tests.

Does Rust offer something else that I don’t yet know about?

(To clarify a bit: I’m not looking for *how* to do any of these things, I can probably figure that out, I was asking for more possibilities than the two I have listed.)

Comment: For the first one you might want to check `std::net::TcpListener` which provides you a `TcpStream` for each connection. For the second one, `TcpStream` already [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#implementations) `std::io::Write` and `std::io::Read` traits, you may expect these traits instead of concrete `TcpStream` for your IO logic.

Comment: _"Does Rust offer something else that I don’t yet know about?"_ Not out of the usual box, other than traits for specifying common behavior. Since `TcpStream` [implements `Read` and `Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#implementations), just follow the advice given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370126/how-can-i-test-stdin-and-stdout).

Comment: Okay, `Read` and `Write` certainly seem viable options but that would still leave me with the necessity to create the `TcpStream`. Normally I would throw a factory at that, is that considered idiomatic in Rust as well? :)

Comment: No, you would make your logic depend on something that implements `Read` and `Write`. From there, you can "mock" the TCP stream by giving it something else that provides the two byte channels.

Comment: Yes, I’m aware of that part but the library I’m writing should be responsible for creating the TCP stream as well so I would somehow need to make that part accessible to tests, too.

Comment: You can spawn a thread to run your code and in your main thread you listen for a connection and check that all is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, since the question is a bit broad, but you can use a  [VecDeque](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html) (double-ended queue) in order to mock a `TcpStream`. It works because both `TcpStream` and `VecDeque` implement the `Read` and `Write` traits, so you can plug-in a `VecDeque` instead of a `TcpStream` to test certain functions.

So instead of doing this:

```rust
fn do_something(
  mut stream: &mut TcpStream,
) {
  // Do something with the TCP Stream
  // (Reads, writes, and other TCP Stream functionalities
}
```

Change the params to this:

```rust
fn do_something<S: std::io::Write + std::io::Read>(
  mut stream: &mut S,
) {
  // Do something with the generic stream
  // (only reads & writes)
}
```

Now the function accepts a `TcpStream` and `VecDeque`, but the latter is way easier to mock and test, as you don't have to setup the server listener nor connect to it with the right port.