# How to capture the content of stdout/stderr when I cannot change the code that prints?

Tags: rust

I have a function `foo` that can't be modified and contains `println!` and `eprintln!` code in it.

```
fn foo() {
    println!("hello");
}
```

After I call the function, I have to test what it printed so I want to capture the stdout/stderr into a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend **against doing this**, but if you are using nightly and don't mind using a feature that seems unlikely to ever be stabilized, you can directly capture stdout and stderr using hidden functionality of the standard library:

```rust
#![feature(internal_output_capture)]

use std::sync::Arc;

fn foo() {
    println!("hello");
    eprintln!("world");
}

fn main() {
    std::io::set_output_capture(Some(Default::default()));
    foo();
    let captured = std::io::set_output_capture(None);

    let captured = captured.unwrap();
    let captured = Arc::try_unwrap(captured).unwrap();
    let captured = captured.into_inner().unwrap();
    let captured = String::from_utf8(captured).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(captured, "hello\nworld\n");
}
```

It's very rare that a function "cannot be changed", so I'd encourage you to do so and use dependency injection instead. For example, if you are *able* to edit `foo` but do not want to change its signature, move all the code to a new function with generics which you can test directly:

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn foo() {
    foo_inner(io::stdout(), io::stderr()).unwrap()
}

fn foo_inner(mut out: impl Write, mut err: impl Write) -> io::Result<()> {
    writeln!(out, "hello")?;
    writeln!(err, "world")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

See also:

- [How can I test stdin and stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28370126/155423)
- [How to take ownership of T from Arc<Mutex<T>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29177449/155423)
- [How do I convert a Vector of bytes (u8) to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37580535/155423)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would work on windows, but should work on unix like systems. You should replace the file descriptor to something you can read later. I don't think it is really easy.

I would suggest to use [`stdio_override`](https://docs.rs/stdio-override/0.1.3/stdio_override/) which already does that for you using files. You can redirect it, then execute the function and the read the file content.

From the [example](https://docs.rs/stdio-override/0.1.3/stdio_override/#examples):

```rust
use stdio_override::StdoutOverride;
use std::fs;
let file_name = "./test.txt";
let guard = StdoutOverride::override_file(file_name)?;
println!("Isan to Stdout!");

let contents = fs::read_to_string(file_name)?;
assert_eq!("Isan to Stdout!\n", contents);
drop(guard);
println!("Outside!");
```

The library also support anything that implements [`AsRawFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/unix/io/trait.AsRawFd.html), through the [`override_raw`](https://docs.rs/stdio-override/0.1.3/stdio_override/struct.StdoutOverride.html#method.override_raw) call. Confirming that it will probably just work on unix.

Otherwise, you can check on the [implementation](https://docs.rs/stdio-override/0.1.3/src/stdio_override/macros.rs.html#41-47) on how it is done internally, and maybe you could bypass a writer instead of a file somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Shadow `println!`:

```rust
use std::{fs::File, io::Write, mem::MaybeUninit, sync::Mutex};

static mut FILE: MaybeUninit<Mutex<File>> = MaybeUninit::uninit();

macro_rules! println {
    ($($tt:tt)*) => {{
        unsafe { writeln!(&mut FILE.assume_init_mut().lock().unwrap(), $($tt)*).unwrap(); }
    }}
}

fn foo() {
    println!("hello");
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        FILE.write(Mutex::new(File::create("out").unwrap()));
    }
    foo();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If `foo` is inside of the user's code, then they could change it. If it's not inside of their code, then shadowing `println` will have no effect.

Comment: "*they could change it*" That contradicts what OP says: "*can't be modified*". OP writes "*I have*" -> hints at being their code but being unable to change it for a foreign reason. For example it could be homework.

Comment: It's very interesting vision to solve the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure @Brad